# Digging deeper into Pandas' implementation

Tags: python, pandas

I can't easily understand the backend of what Pandas does.

For instance, I created a df of means. As I wanted, `df.mean` only took the mean of numeric columns, ignoring my object column such as "School Name". I noticed that when trying to create a dataframe of sums, the `df.sum` attempted to take the sum of objects like "School Name", and I saw in the docs that you could add the argument `numeric_only=True`. However, the docs state that both `df.mean` and `df.sum` "will attempt to use everything" first if you did not set that argument. So my question became, "why did `df.mean` work without setting the argument `numeric_only`?"

When trying to investigate `df.mean`, quickdocs took me over to `cls.mean = _make_stat_function(...nanops.nanmean)`. OK, while trying to investigate `nanmean` there is no argument available for `numeric_only`. The only arguments defined for `nanmean` in the quickdocs are as follows:
`def nanmean(values, axis=None, skipna=True, mask=None)`.

So where could I find stuff like Pandas' implementation of `df.mean`? What process do I need to use if not quickdocs?

**My question isn't about `df.mean` in particular but rather, *what do I need to click to easily find the source code* because it appears quickdocs skimped over some?** Also I'm working in PyCharm.

Comment: It's probably because you can add strings, but you can't take the mean of strings. So pandas is able to sum the `School Name`, but not divide by the number of elements.

Comment: It's not an answer to your questions, but rather an intuition about the difference between the behaviors of `.mean()` and `.sum()`. By default the sum can allow different datatypes because `1+1==2`, and `'a'+'b' == 'ab'`. Both have logical answers to summation, so it's necessary to exclude non-numeric. However, `mean([1,1]) == 1`, but `mean('ab')==???` so it's unnecessary to explicitly remove those

Comment: are you working in a jupyter notebook or console? if so `pandas.DataFrame??` will show you the source code of that class

Comment: The full source code can be browsed and downloaded here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/

Comment: Specifically, the docs for `nanmean` are in the [nanops.py](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/nanops.py) source